# tooltip not working in edge browser in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add tootltip in bootstrap but it seems something wrong with browser. When I open page in edge tooltip="bottom" not working properly. but i chrome its works fine. but one thing i observed is that there is no align right or left along button option for tool tip. Please have any idea about it??
Here is my code

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                     <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Or call us at +812 222134" data-placement="right"  class="btn btn-warning btn-block " href="#Reserve">Reserve Table</a></button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem I dint activate tooltip option in jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
         });
```